# How to kill a buffer when it causes Emacs to stop responding?

Tags: buffers, debugging, frozen-emacs

I use Emacs Dired to manage files. Accidentally, I hit Enter on an image file, Emacs tries to open the image and stop response. Is there a way to kill this process?

(Since I am running other processes at the same time, I don't want to restart Emacs.)

**Edit**: 
Is there a way to list all the processes within Emacs and kill a certain one like in shell: `kill -9 process-id`?

**Edit 2**: 
Although very slow, I managed to press `C-x C-b` to list all the buffers, and `d` mark the buffer caused Emacs no-response, `x` to execute delete. It succeed.

This only works as long as Emacs could response to my key. I really don't know what to do if I can't list all the buffers.

Comment: Did you hold `C-g` for a while?

Comment: @TuDo Yes, I did. It didn't work. I also tried `C-x k`,  I saw this in mini-buffer: `Error in nil (nil): (quit)`

Comment: Try `C-x C-b` `C-x o` `d x`.

Comment: @abo-abo Thank you. I tried almost the same approach and it worked.

Answer (score 12):

Press <kbd>C-g</kbd> repeatably. The first time might be ignored, the second time it should do the trick. If that fails also try pressing <kbd>ESC</kbd> three times.

Answer (score 12):

I've personally experienced hangs that cannot be broken by any number of <kbd>C-g</kbd> presses.

A more forceful method on UNIX OSs is to send Emacs a USR2 signal. Signal processing is a lot lower-level than keyboard input, and has a very good chance of unhanging Emacs. (I've never seen it fail)

```
$ killall -USR2 emacs
```

Should do the trick. In addition USR2 creates a backtrace. If you don't want that, you might have some luck with the following (I haven't tested this, though):

```el
(defun quit-on-usr2 ()
  (interactive)
  (keyboard-quit))
(global-set-key [signal usr2] #'quit-on-usr2)
```

Comment: This is quite old, but just came across it. Can you explain the [signal usr2] part. I haven't seen that as a keystroke before.

Comment: Never mind: Thank you for this, this allowed me to construct a useful technique to stop a runaway Emacs timer when C-g doesn't respond. For others, I think you got this from: https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Event-Examples.html#Event-Examples

Comment: Your answer gave birth to this, which works really well for me: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/506/debugging-a-frozen-emacs/70000#70000