# Tell emacsclient/server to stop whatever it's doing (from another terminal window perhaps)

Tags: terminal-emacs, xml, frozen-emacs

I opened an .xml file inside `emacsclient -nw` not realizing it's large (55MB)

Now I'm staring at my terminal/emacs for several minutes. It seems frozen but I know from experience it will eventually wake up after (I'm guessing) xml mode parses the file.

(I did try C-g multiple times)

In a situation like this, what are my options..

Is there a *SIGNAL* I can send the pid of emacs/emacsclient to tell it to "stop whatever thing you're doing"

Suppose I knew the file was large, how can I tell emacs to open it, but don't try any fancy xml parsing modes, just go `fundamental`.

Comment: [Here is a reference](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/7893/53) to SIGUSR2 as a lower-level break than C-g or ESC repeatedly.