# Tramp session fails to recover from inactivity

Tags: tramp

When a Tramp session over SSH has been inactive for some time, it fails to wake up again and just hangs Emacs. How can I ensure that Tramp will either renew the connection, or time out before too long?

The hang is evident from the minibuffer message:

> Decoding remote file ‘/ssh:foohost:/home/bignose/barfile.txt’ using ‘base64 -d -i >%s’

and an animated spinner, that spins endlessly for tens of minutes without result.

During this, Emacs is hung: it doesn't respond to any commands or keys, not even `keyboard-quit` (<kbd>C-g</kbd>).

This is Emacs version 25.2.

How can I convince Emacs that Tramp sessions should be re-established when they time out, instead of waiting forever?

Comment: If Emacs is stuck, see tips in https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/506/debugging-a-frozen-emacs for recovering. It might not help you make Tramp work but it should at least give you an opportunity to save your files locally.

Answer (score 1):

After the `tramp-cleanup-all-connections` command, you can just continue and a new session will be established on any further `tramp` action.

Answer (score 0):

Abort with `C-g`, then kill the tramp buffers :

Open the buffer list with `C-x C-b`, locate anything **tramp** and mark them for deletion (`d`) then execute (`x`) you can now use Tramp again.

Comment: “Abort with C-g […]” — as noted in the question, Emacs is unresponsive (including C-g) while it is waiting for the SSH command to run.