# How to debug frequent emacs feezes

Tags: debug

I have a complex Emacs setup. I love it, except for that fact that it freezes a couple of times a day for me. I have a few suspicion:

1. I use `you-complete-me` for auto-completion in c++ and it may be hanging on RPC call to the YMCD server.
2. I use `el-get` package manager and it occasionally checks with the server.

The problem is that another colleague has almost the same setup and his Emacs does not hang. How would I debug something like this?

Comment: Use your colleague's setup. ;-)

Comment: You can run Emacs under gdb for day to day use until you catch it in the act of freezing ....  Build Emacs from source, open the terminal, cd to the ../src directory (to take advantage of gdbinit), then launch gdb ... path/to/emacs that was built from source.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Debugging a frozen Emacs](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/506/debugging-a-frozen-emacs)

Answer (score 2):

1. `M-x toggle-debug-on-quit`
2. Hit `C-g` when running into the freeze
3. ????
4. PROFIT

Don't forget running `M-x toggle-debug-on-quit` again after successful debugging, it's rather annoying to have every `C-g` spawn the debugger.

Comment: On a unixish OS, `pkill -SIGUSR2 emacs` when Emacs is stuck can work too.

Comment: Put that in your own answer.