# Where is mhtml mode defined? And why am I getting it by default when I open HTML files?

Tags: major-mode, html

Under some *very special* conditions (namely, performing one particular edit in one particular HTML file), my Emacs session will freeze completely, and starts consuming ~100% of the CPU.  The only course of action at this point is to put the poor beast to sleep (with well-aimed `kill -9`; it won't work without the `-9`).

I'm trying out characterize the conditions that lead to this behavior.

All I know is that it happens, as I wrote, when I perform a particular edit on this one particular file, AND the major mode for the file is `mhtml`.  (The problem does not occur if I perform the same edit on that same file while the active mode is plain-ol' `Fundamental`.)

I can't figure out why `mhtml` is the initial major mode for this file (when I open it).

If I search for `mhtml` in my `.emacs` file, I get no hits.  Is `mhtml` the default mode for HTML files?

(For what it's worth, the packages listed by `list-packages` do not mention `mhtml` at all.)

Bottom line is: I can't figure out what `mhtml` mode is, or why I'm getting it by default.  It may be something I have in my `.emacs`, but if so, it's not obvious to me what it is.

Comment: [`mhtml-mode` is default for `*.html` files in emacs 26.1[(http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs.git/commit/etc/NEWS?id=335174ee5037a2751c31bfd9ecb87cedb4bc3cda) I don't have emacs 26.1. So I cannot test it. Maybe, you can remove `nhtml-mode` from `auto-mode-alist`.

Comment: It does not solve your problem, but when emacs is frozen you can try to send it the signal SIGUSR2, see [this answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/649/11725) for details

Comment: @matteol: Thank you!!!  That's an extremely useful tip.

Comment: I also noticed that mhtml-mode has a problem with quotes within JavaScript comments when finding matching braces. I just installed web-mode, which does not have the comment problem and might also fix your freezing problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`mhtml-mode` is defined in `mhtml-mode.el`. You can find it using `M-x find-function mhtml-mode`.

Other interesting commands for locating/finding libraries:

- With <kbd>M-x</kbd> **`locate-library`** <kbd>RET</kbd> `mhtml-mode` <kbd>RET</kbd> the file name is displayed in the echo area.
- With <kbd>M-x</kbd> **`find-library`** <kbd>RET</kbd> `mhtml-mode` <kbd>RET</kbd> the library file opened.
- The help page for `mhtml-mode` contains a link to the file where that command is defined near the top. The help page can be opened with the command `describe-function` which is bound to <kbd>C-h f</kbd> `mhtml-mode` <kbd>RET</kbd>.