# Random freezes with `error in process filter: Quit`

Tags: tramp

I'm getting random freezes with the error message: `error in process filter: Quit`. I'm using tramp-mode with emacs 26.1 on macOS. It seems to maybe be linked to typing symbol characters like %, $, etc. but that could just be a coincidence.

Comment: Do you have a chance to get a backtrace? By setting `debug-on-quit` to `t`, or alike.

Comment: I added one, but emacs is so frozen that it doesn't even repaint the screen. If I try resizing it, all I get is a blank canvas.

Comment: Same issue on emacs 28.1 on macOS. Only happens over TRAMP. I have a feeling it's linked to `company` and/or `eglot`, but I'm not sure. If others have this issue, reporting on whether those or other autocomplete/LSP modes are enabled would be helpful.

Comment: Experiencing the same (very rare) random freeze with 90% CPU load on emacs 27.1 with no tramp (or eglot) packages installed.

Answer (score 0):

When Emacs is stuck like this, it is possible to [make it break out into its Lisp debugger](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/506/debugging-a-frozen-emacs) by sending the signal`SIGUSR2` to the process.
You have to do this probable twice, and it will give you the Emacs callstack in a Backtrace buffer.
In my case this is

`Debugger entered--entering a function:
*#f(compiled-function () #<bytecode 0x155f1e17fa01>)()
compilation-filter(# #("Widgets/QTreeView:1\33[m\33[K,\15\n                 from ..." 0 4095 (charset iso-8859-1)))
accept-process-output(#)
flyspell-word()
flyspell-post-command-hook()
recursive-edit()
debug(error (quit))
delete-and-extract-region(1537016 1537019)
ansi-color-apply-on-region(1536145 1540211)
colorize-compilation-buffer()
run-hooks(compilation-filter-hook)
compilation-filter(# #("ate argument must be a complete class or an unboun..." 0 4095 (charset iso-8859-1)))
accept-process-output(#)
flyspell-word()
flyspell-post-command-hook()`

I'm not sure that this means there is a problem with `flyspell`.